# When using torchvision.ops.roi_align, I got the error:Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: pytorch, roi, torchvision

My environment:torch-1.2, torchvision-0.3, python-3.7. I also tried other visions like torchvision-0.5, torchvision-0.6, but always got this error. What should I do could sovle this?